# How to edit Geometry Node Input with python

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

How do I control Geometry Node Input with python?

When I do it manually the Info Scripting panel says this:

```
bpy.context.object.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_2"] = 50
```

But I have a bunch of objects I want to control the value of, and I can't figure out how to do so.

I want to control the value the same way I control its scale like this:

```
cubes = bpy.data.collections["Cubes"].objects
while i < 10:
   cubes[i].scale[2] = listA[i]/2
   i += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It works the same way, but the interface to GN modifier inputs is a bit weird. Assuming you have the same GN modifier on all your cubes, do :

```
import bpy

cubes = bpy.data.collections["Cubes"].objects
for i, cube in enumerate(cubes):
    cube.modifiers["GeometryNodes"]["Input_2"] = i
```